# How to Run Multiple Scrapy Spiders in Sequence?

Tags: python, scrapy

My code:
It's code start scrapy spiders

```
def start_crawling():
    spiders = [spdier1, spider2]
    runner = CrawlerProcess()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl():
        for spider in spiders:
            yield runner.crawl(spider, (task.id, True, None))
        reactor.stop()

    while True:
        a = time.time()
        crawl()
        reactor.run()
        print("crawl time: " + str(time.time() - a))

if name == "main": 
   start_crawling()
```

But i have an error:
`twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`
How i can fix this?

log error:

```
2022-12-27 21:10:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-12-27 21:10:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled   pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-12-27 21:10:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//./scraper.py", line 49, in <module>
start_crawling()
File "//./scraper.py", line 44, in start_crawling
reactor.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1317, in run
self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1299, in 
ReactorBase.startRunning(cast(ReactorBase, self))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 843, in 
raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You're not showing all of your code: only showing the function definition. Where did you call this function? Also, when you get an error, it is always more useful to add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @Koedlt, if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_crawling()

Comment: Edit your question to add that information so that all reviewers can see it :) Also, add the full error traceback. Else reviewers don't know where the error happened.